Usage of breakfast to refer to breaking a fast
When referring to eating to end a religious fast, is it appropriate to refer to it as breakfast?
I found a source that says: "Breakfast gets its name from “break” and “fast,” because it is the meal eaten when you “break” the overnight “fast” from food."
So can this be applied to any other fast?

Note that breakfast is not pronounced as break fast, but brekfust. At a religious festival you would say sth like "I am breaking my fast".

You could look in a dictionary and see if it gives "breaking a fast" as a meaning. And the original meaning of "breaking a fast" was to cut short a fast prematurely or fail to observe a fast (OED), not to eat at the alloted endpoint, so it definitely wouldn't be appropriate for a meal after a fast such as Iftar.
